# Remove_action inside a function

Tags: wp-head

HI there,

I want to remove the actions added to wp_head by a plugin but only in certain circumstances.

Here is code that doesn't work:

```
if (is_single() && get_post_type()  == 'tenant') {
  $row = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM Events WHERE WP_ID='$post->ID'",ARRAY_A);
  remove_action('wp-head',array($aiosp, 'wp_head'));
  $seo_head = "<title>" . $row['Event'] . " | " . $row['Town'] . 
              " | Events in ". $row['Country'] . "</title>";
}
```

Comment: Are you sure $aiosp isn't null?

Comment: You need to give more information so we can help you. It would be useful to know the context in which you are running the code you say that doesn't work and what you'd expect it to do if it were working per your wishes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted it, turns out all-in-one-seo-pack can be disabled on a post by post basis, so I used:
add_post_meta($post->ID,'_aioseop_disable',true); inside the if parameter and before setting my own title, works a charm.

PS $post is gotten with global $post;

Comment: Please mark this as "the" answer so that future readers know what to do to fix the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that it's not working because the action name is `'wp_head'`, not `'wp-head'`.

```
remove_action('wp_head',array($aiosp, 'wp_head'));
```